# GSON not saving new fields to file

Tags: java, gson

I'm adding new fields to my data class, they're not saving to file. None of the fields are transient.

I'm loading the file with GSON then resaving it to try to save new fields. I've tried setting the fields in the constructor and just setting them on creation. Neither worked, I also tried saving the file in the traditional way using GSON, that didn't work either. Modifying already existing fields works and they save properly, but new fields are never created.

```java
private void loadUserData(Player player) {
    File userFile = new File(userFolder + File.separator + player.getUniqueId().toString() + ".json");

    try {
        if (!userFile.exists()) {
            User user = new User(player.getUniqueId(), player.getName(), player.isOp() ? "§8(§9Manager§8) §9" : "§7", "");

            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(userFile, new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create().toJson(user), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            userCache.put(player.getUniqueId(), user);
        } else {
            User user = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new FileReader(userFile), User.class);

            user.save();

            if(!userCache.containsKey(player.getUniqueId())) {
                userCache.put(player.getUniqueId(), user);
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```java
public void save() {
    File userFolder = new File(Core.getInstance().getModuleManager().getModuleInstance(SMPModule.class).getDataFolder() + File.separator + "users");

    try {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File( userFolder + File.separator + uuid.toString() + ".json"),
                new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create().toJson(this), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Data Class:

```java
package net.astreul.core.module.impl.SMP.user;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Setter;
import net.astreul.core.Core;
import net.astreul.core.module.impl.SMP.SMPModule;
import net.astreul.core.module.impl.SMP.cosmetic.CosmeticPackage;
import net.astreul.core.util.Format;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Setter
public class User {

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE) private UUID uuid;
    private String nickname;
    private String prefix;
    private String suffix;
    private long lastLogin;
    private List<CosmeticPackage> ownedCosmetics;
    private List<String> ownedTags;
    private String activeTag;

    public User(UUID uuid, String nickname, String prefix, String suffix) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        lastLogin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ownedCosmetics = Lists.newArrayList();
        ownedTags = Lists.newArrayList();
        this.activeTag = "";
    }

    public void save() {
        File userFolder = new File(Core.getInstance().getModuleManager().getModuleInstance(SMPModule.class).getDataFolder() + File.separator + "users");

        try {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File( userFolder + File.separator + uuid.toString() + ".json"),
                    new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create().toJson(this));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public File getFile() {
        File userFolder = new File(Core.getInstance().getModuleManager().getModuleInstance(SMPModule.class).getDataFolder() + File.separator + "users");
        return new File( userFolder + File.separator + uuid.toString() + ".json");
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return Format.color(nickname);
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return Format.color(prefix);
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return Format.color(suffix);
    }

    public long getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public boolean hasPackage(CosmeticPackage cosmeticPackage) {
        return ownedCosmetics.contains(cosmeticPackage);
    }

    public List<CosmeticPackage> getOwnedCosmetics() {
        return ownedCosmetics;
    }

    public List<String> getOwnedTags() {
        return ownedTags;
    }

    public String getActiveTag() {
        return activeTag;
    }
}
```

I expected it to save the new fields to file, but it didn't save anything at all. There was no error at all.

Comment: Could you please show how your data class is defined?

Comment: Yeah, I've edited the post.

Comment: Are the new fields `lastLogin`,  `ownedCosmetics`, `ownedTags` and `activeTag`? Essentially, all that are initialized in the constructor?

Comment: No, those fields are already in the user files. What I was suggesting is that if I add any new fields, even if I add them to the constructor they don't get saved to the file.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's happening, but it's too big for a comment. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is related to how gson creates instances.

If you look at the source code of gson you'll find that it tries to create the object instances using one of 3 things. First it tries instance creators - entities that know how to create an object. You can register one yourself  to create the user - check [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html)

If there's none it'll check for default constructors, which you don't have. A default constructor is one that has no arguments.

The last step is a best effort to create the object and it uses Java's [unsafe](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe). As the name suggests this is unsafe to do and the reason is because it bypasses all constructors. In your case, it'll bypass any initialization you have put inside the constructor and will leave the fields that are not in the json as null.

If you don't change the fields externally, once you save the user object, the new fields are still null and hence not saved.

To fix this, you can provide an instance creator, or initialize the fields from another method or somehow provide a default constructor.